# Kali Linux + Windows-To-Go Multiboot USB?

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, kali-linux

I just bought a Patriot 256GB USB. I want to run Kali Linux (with encrypted persistence) and Windows To Go (Server 2019 or Windows 10.) I've used YUMI and Sardu for multiple Linux Live USB and Persistence (Casper-RW.) I currently have one with Mint, Ubuntu, Kali, a few Anti-Viruses' and Hiren's boot CD. It works fine. Can I create a single USB with Kali and Server 2019? Or any Windows 10? Kali needs persistence or encrypted persistence. I've tried making Windows To Go before but never had a USB fast enough to run it. It worked but would take hours to start up. I think I created it using Rufus. Or another. And it was Windows 10 not Windows Server. I read about "Ventoy" but I don't know if it will create Windows To Go or just the Windows installer. Does anyone know any ways to install Kali + Windows? Free Software? What about a VHD or VHDX? I have a Server 2019 VM on VMware. Can I copy that to the USB? Partition it? Please reply. Thanks

Comment: What did you end up using?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a multi-partition GPT style USB drive sounds possible, but complicated to create and maintain. However, depending on what your real world use case is you might try a solution called [Easy2Boot](https://www.easy2boot.com/).

I've been using Easy2Boot for years as an all-in-one troubleshooting / utility usb stick containing a trove of Linux live ISOs, Windows PE ISOs, and random bootable bios / firmware images. I don't need persistent storage for my needs, but the [FAQ](https://www.easy2boot.com/faq-/) suggests that this is supported. The thing that I like most about Easy2Boot is that I can just add or remove ISOs to / from the drive without the need to manage separate partitions or a boot manager.

If running a "real" Windows installation is something that you need, Easy2Boot also appears to support [Windows To Go](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-to-go-overview) style installations and VHDs (see FAQ / documentation). However, I would take this with a grain of salt as Windows To Go is no longer officially supported by Microsoft, so might not be the best solution. I also don't think Windows Server was ever officially supported by Windows To Go as it was intended for sharing desktop hardware in educational and enterprise environments.

One problem with Easy2Boot is that the website is a bit dated in terms of design and can be difficult to navigate. They have extensive documentation and [forums](https://www.easy2boot.com/forum/), but locating what you're looking for can take some effort.

For anyone else that is coming here looking for Windows To Go information, I'll add a link to an article from pcmag.com that provides a [tutorial for creating a dedicated Windows 10 To Go drive](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/how-to-run-windows-10-from-a-usb-drive) using [WinToUSB](http://www.easyuefi.com/wintousb/) and / or [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/).